# How to read a text file and add lines of it into an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, io, populate

I am new to coding and I was wondering how I would be able to add the lines of my text file into an array in my program. My code looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
    
    static String [] name = new String [3];
    static String [] surname = new String [3];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader reader =null;
            String currentLine = reader.readLine();
            reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Names.txt"));

            int x=0;
            
            while(currentLine!=null){
                name[x]=reader.readLine();
                currentLine=reader.readLine();
                surname[x]=reader.readLine();
                currentLine=reader.readLine();
                x=x+1;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("The following error occured:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        for(int x =0; x<name.length; x++){
            System.out.println(
            "name:" + name[x] + "\n"+
            "surname: " + surname[x] +"\n"
            );
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting is `Cannot invoke "java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()" because "reader" is null`. How do I fix that?

Comment: Your currentLine is null, therefore, it never enters the while loop that you have where the statement is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- BufferedReader object is null and you are trying to access which is not possible in java.
- I didn`t get what exactly you try to do but you can do something like this.

```
public class Task3 {

    static String [] name = new String [3];
    static String [] surname = new String [3];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader reader =null;
            reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/ancubate/names.txt"));
            List<String> lines = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
            int x=0;
            
            while(lines.size() != (x+1)){
                name[x]=lines.get(x);
                surname[x]=lines.get(x);
                x=x+1;
                
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("The following error occured:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        for(int x =0; x<name.length; x++){
            System.out.println(
            "name:" + name[x] + "\n"+
            "surname: " + surname[x] +"\n"
            );
        }
    }

}
```

- reader.lines() - to get all the lines from the file
- collect(Collectors.toList()) - stream API collect as list

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of my answer. I think it is because you forgot to import java io package into the program. Hope you got it.

Comment: I did add it but its still giving the same error unfortunately.

Comment: In case of uncertainty please prefer comment over answer